# Building simulation of tilt maze - calculating surface height of tilted table

Tags: 3d, geometry, xna-4.0, game-physics, monogame

I'm building a tilt maze game/simulation.  A tilt maze is a maze where a user can tilt the surface of a table to move a marble or ball bearing around a maze.

I'm doing this in monogame and it's a right handed coordinate system with Y being the up direction.  I calculate the X and Z with newtonian physics but I'm having trouble positioning the height of the sphere so it doesn't float over or go into the table.

The surface of the maze is limited to tilting 10deg in both the X and Z dimensions.  This is pretty easy to do in 2D as it's just the sin(rotationAngRadians) * vectorLength.  I've tried a number of approaches for 3D and getting nowhere fast.

I have both the X and Z angles for the table and the ball position as a vector.  I know that Y=1 is on top of the table when both X and Z angles are 0.  If the Z angle rotation is 10 deg (imagine a level playing card to tilting down on the right.), then Y needs to be greater than 1 if X is negative and less than 1 if X is positive.

Here are a couple of jpgs of a tilt maze and a sphere.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwmfnottzmgynjc/tiltGame1.jpg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6k4unt6hukumyos/tiltGame2.jpg

I have tried creating separate rotation matrixes for X and Z and then multiplying the spherePosition, etc but that's not working correctly.

Anyone have any pointers for what I should read or look at?

Thanks,

Erik

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: It sounds like you're setting the position of the sphere yourself instead of letting the physics engine control it? Is that right?

Comment: Yes I'm setting the sphere position.  There is no physics engine involved.  I'm doing all the physics myself.  This is an assignment for a UMN Motion Planning in Games class so I can't use a physics engine.

Comment: I ended up creating a plane at the height and orientation as the tilt maze.  You can use Plane.Transform to tilt the plane.  I then used a Ray to project up and return where it hit the tilt maze.  The intersection of the ray + amount the plane was below the maze + the radius of the sphere keeps the sphere planted on the tilt maze.